# How to upload image using Retrofit2 and save it on NodeJS server?

Tags: android, node.js, post, retrofit

I have android app that posts image to NodeJS server using Retrofit2.
Here is my Android/Java code:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    String ENDPOINT = "http://192.168.0.11:1337/";

    @Multipart
    @POST("users/avatar")
    Call<Avatar> postAvatar(@Part("description") RequestBody description, @Part("image") MultipartBody.Part file);

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .build();
}

private void uploadAvatar(final String userid){
     File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bcg.loginexample/files/pic.jpg");

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);
        String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
        RequestBody description =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

        ApiInterface mApiService = ApiInterface.retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Avatar> mService=  mApiService.postAvatar(description, body );
        mService.enqueue(new Callback<Avatar>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Avatar> call, Response<Avatar> response) {
                Avatar avatar = response.body();
                String returnedResponse = avatar.avatar_url;
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Returned " + returnedResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Avatar> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And NodeJS

```
app.post('/users/avatar', type,
  function (req, res) {
     var filePath = __dirname + '/uploads/avatar.jpg';
     fs.appendFile(filePath, req.body.image, function () {
       res.end('file uploaded');
     });
  });
```

This is all I see in body object at NodeJS side.

```
"{"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Disposition","form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"pic.jpg\""]}}"
```

Don't understand where is the image here and how to save it ??

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra middleware to handle multipart/form-data (upload of binary data). You can take a look at the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) module for example.

Comment: I tried multer but the problem is there is no file in the request

Comment: Depending on the multer method you use the file information will be in either `req.file` or `req.files`. If neither contains any information check that your POST request is correct. (e.g. try using the `curl` command to post a file to your destination to verify that the problem is not related to your backend)